# make extern variable globally visible across all projects in sln file

Tags: c, global

project_1.vcproj contains:
header_1.h has "extern int flag;" is declared.
source_1.c has "int flag = 0" initialized

project_2.vcproj contains:
source_2.c has a function which modifies the value of flag.

```
#include "header_1.h"
 void setFlag() {
    flag = 1;
}
```

When I try to compile this I get link errors:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int flag"

What I am trying to achieve is I want the value of flag to be visible globally. 
Because after the flag is set to 1, source_1.c uses this information do other things.

Please let me know how to achieve me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `#include "header_1.h"` at the top of `source_2.c`.

Also make sure `source_1.c` is included in project_2.

Answer (score 0):

Project_2 must include header_1.h or Project_2 must declare `extern int flag`. Either way, you will need to link Project_2 against the actual storage location of `int flag`. Otherwise, project_2 won't manipulate the value of `int flag` in located in Project_1.

Answer (score 0):

extract `int flag = 0` into separate .c file and add that source file into both projects